# Read various files and write it to one Excel sheet using Python, Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, glob

Doesnt matter what i do, id ont get it done that alle the data from the xhtml files will be written in one Excel sheet. It looks like, that Python llops through all my files in the folder but as output i only get the data from the last file.
Help would be great!

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

# Import libaries
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import glob
import time

#Path to folder
path_dir: str = r"C:\Users\Moench\Desktop\r2d2\EPUB\content1\*.xhtml"

#Read files
for filename in glob.glob(path_dir):

#Assign the table data to a Pandas dataframe 
        dfs = open(filename, 'r')
        dfs1 = pd.read_html(dfs)

#Read data                                                                                                         
        df2 = dfs1[0][['Unnamed: 0_level_0','Unnamed: 1_level_0','Unnamed: 2_level_0','Unnamed: 3_level_0','Unnamed: 4_level_0','Unnamed: 12_level_0','Unnamed: 13_level_0']]
 
#Print result (Looks like that it goes through all files in the folder)
#        print (df2)

# Write to existing Excel-Sheet
book = load_workbook('output.xlsx')
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx', engine='openpyxl') 
writer.book = book
ts = time.time()

df3 = df2.append(df2) 
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)
df3.to_excel(writer, str(ts))
writer.save()
```

Comment: Are you trying to write all dataframes read from `content1\*.html` in one excel spreadsheet ?
self-rep : i got it

Comment: your `df2` variable is overwritten in each step in for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are storing your data at each iteration in the same dataframe, rewriting it at each iteration, so you only have your last data (twice actually, because of `df2.append(df2)`.

Here is a slightly modified version, storing each dataframe in `df_list`, and using `pd.concat` on this list to create `df3`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

# Import libaries
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import glob
import time

#Path to folder
path_dir: str = r"C:\Users\Moench\Desktop\r2d2\EPUB\content1\*.xhtml"

# Initiate list of dataframes
df_list = list()

#Read files
for filename in glob.glob(path_dir):

#Assign the table data to a Pandas dataframe 
        dfs = open(filename, 'r')
        dfs1 = pd.read_html(dfs)

#Read data                                                                                                         
        df2 = dfs1[0][['Unnamed: 0_level_0','Unnamed: 1_level_0','Unnamed: 2_level_0','Unnamed: 3_level_0','Unnamed: 4_level_0','Unnamed: 12_level_0','Unnamed: 13_level_0']]
       
        df_list.append(df2)
 
#Print result (Looks like that it goes through all files in the folder)
#        print (df2)

# Write to existing Excel-Sheet
book = load_workbook('output.xlsx')
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx', engine='openpyxl') 
writer.book = book
ts = time.time()

# Concatenate all dataframes into one
df3 = pd.concat(df_list, ignore_index=True) 

writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)
df3.to_excel(writer, str(ts))
writer.save()
```